# Microsoft bond c++ runtime deserialization using runtime schema

Tags: c++, bond

I could not find anything useful in their docs or examples :(
They have docs of how to deserialize schema, and then how to traverse it - that works great.
They have also two examples:

1. how to use `bond::bonded<void>` with runtime schema to convert binary to json
2. how to use `bond::bonded<void>` with runtime schema and `MapTo` to parse data into some custom ViewStruct

What I need is: to traverse the `bond:bonded<void>` to extract fields from it.

In protobuf you have field descriptors (created using `FinFieldByName`) and then you use them in runtime methods `msg->getString, msg->getInt32` to get the typed value.

Comment: Looks like you're asking two questions. You may wish to re-write the question to focus on one.

Comment: nope, it is one question

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing built in that allows you to traverse a `bonded<void>` and inspect its fields. If you need to do that generically, you'll need to implement a custom [transform](https://microsoft.github.io/bond/manual/bond_cpp.html#transforms) and then use `bond::Apply()` to apply the transform to a `bonded<void>` constructed from a reader and a runtime schema. See in particular the [transform](https://github.com/microsoft/bond/tree/master/examples/cpp/core/transform) and [access_control](https://github.com/microsoft/bond/tree/master/examples/cpp/core/access_control) examples for how to start writing a transform.

Bond needs this level of indirection compared to Protocol Buffers because Bond supports pluggable encoding protocols. If you know that you will only have to process [a specific protocol](https://microsoft.github.io/bond/manual/bond_cpp.html#protocols), you could use that protocol's reader type with the runtime schema to walk the fields in the payload. See [Microsoft Bond deserialization without knowing underlying schema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70884737/microsoft-bond-deserialization-without-knowing-underlying-schema) for a C# example of the core of this algorithm.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. Any examples besides their protocol impls? I tried searching in github and did not find anything useful. I am surprised no projects use it ...

Comment: I updated this answer to link to transform examples. There isn't an example of parsing protocols directly in the Bond repo, as that isn't often done. Could your edit your question to expand on "to traverse the bond:bonded<void> to extract fields from it."? Maybe [views](https://microsoft.github.io/bond/manual/compiler.html#struct-views) would work? [Merge](https://microsoft.github.io/bond/manual/bond_cpp.html#merge)? (At Microsoft, we have a C# tool for debugging corrupt payloads that parses Compact Binary like in the linked question. This tool isn't open source, so I can't share it.)